# pgr_nodeNetwork taking a very long time to run

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I am using `pgr_nodeNetwork` from the extension `pgrouting` of PostGIS/PostgreSQL.

I'm currently running this algorithm on an edges table (it's a network of roads) that contains approx. 100,000 edges. It has been 17 hours and the query still hasn't ended.

Is it ordinary for this algorithm to run for such a long time?

Comment: Not really, I ran pgr_nodeNetwork on 50,000 record and it took just 11 sec

Comment: My experience with pgr_nodeNetwork and related function are bad for bigger data sets.  Finally i wrote my own data loaders that do the job (joining/spliting edges, snapping etc.).
I tried to load around 250 000 edges and it took ages.

Comment: I was wrong in my original post: there were not 100 000 edges in my table, but approximately 3,600,000. The algorithm finished in 26.5 hours.

Comment: In the past I have worked on a similar sized dataset had was also struggling with the processing time. I found that using Grass's Clean tool in QGIS was blazingly fast. Running it outside of QGIS is a lot slower for some reason though.